# Why do Enter and Space keys behave differently for buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms

As far as I know, these are the only keys that react when a button has focus.

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> instantly 'clicks' the button, even if you keep it the key down. (So the 'click' happens on KeyDown).

Pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> acts more like a normal mouse click; holding it down doesn't activate the Click event, but it does once you release it. (So the 'click' happens on KeyUp or KeyPressed.)

Why the difference? I'd like a good article on the subject or simply a logical explanation as to why those two keys have different behavior. Surely there's an explanation out there!

Comment: Enter is to accept, Esc is to reject, Space bar is to press the focused button. So if the default button is the OK, when you press Enter you actually accept the changes and not press the button.

Comment: That is false in the case of a `MessageBox`. Enter and space both click the focused button, but with the behavior described above.

Comment: On the message box, the OK button have the focus, so its as I say. The one have the focus is get the space bar as click, The enter is accept the message box, the esc is reject it and close it.

Comment: You forgot about `MessageBox` with buttons such as OK and CANCEL, YES and NO. The button with the focus (Let's say it's CANCEL) will get activated when you press enter, thus cancelling and closing.

Comment: You can move your select Button to another Button by:
AnotherButton.Select();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't find any articles explaining this and it's a really good question. I personally think that it's for functionality purposes

<kbd>Enter Key</kbd> the classic `AcceptButton` acts like a `FullClick` (Click/ClickReleased) that's why if you hold it you will have the effect of clicking multiple times.

<kbd>Space</kbd> however is a `SingleClick` (No click release until you release the key) so it can accomplish task where only a `Click` is required without a `ClickRelease` and actions where only the selection of a control is required to activate it. Like the `CheckBox` or `RadioButtons` which can't be activate with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> but can be activated with the <kbd>Space</kbd> like if you click on it.

In conclusion, the <kbd>Space</kbd> would be the official `MouseClick` since it has the same effects of a `MouseClick` uppon pressing or releasing. <kbd>Enter</kbd> would be sort of a shortcut for a *One click full click*. All, of course, in the idea of giving more possibilities to the keyboard itself.

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing two different behaviors, which aren't associated except that they both deal with keyboard events on a winform.

<kbd>Enter</kbd> is special because it's the keypress to activate the [acceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) of a form.  In fact, you missed another key that can affect buttons: <kbd>Esc</kbd> is the [cancelButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx), and will throw events as well.

As PhaDaPhunk explained, <kbd>Space</kbd> is a `MouseClick` for any component that accepts a MouseClick, but I haven't found a detailed explanation for it.  I'd assume it's the default behavior of all controls.  The Microsoft guide to [accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb545462.aspx) seems to imply that is so in their section on **keyboard-based navigation**

Incidentally, this [Microsoft support knowledge base entry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955938) seems to show that the spacebar implementation went from Button.Click to Button.MouseClick.  Perhaps that's the reason for it's different behavior.

Comment: Is it possible that in the case of a MessageBox with only an `OK` button, <kbd>esc</kbd> activates the top-right X ? (I don't know how to format keyboard keys)

Comment: Re formatting keys, I found out how to do so by editing your post and then canceling.  Apparently, it's <kbd>Key</kbd>.  As for your question, that seems right, but I'd have to look into it further.  The form has a settable field for cancelButton.

Comment: I would accept your answer for it's thoroughness, however it is not exact I believe. If a MessageBox with `MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel` buttons has the focus on it's cancel button, `Enter` will activate the Cancel button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769951/c-sharp-cancelbutton-closes-dialog talks a bit about the relationship between the x and the cancelButton, but doesn't answer your question about <kbd>Esc</kbd> when there is no cancelButton set.  The best way to see that is to make a basic experiment and see.  I was inaccurate in mentioning `panel` for acceptButton.  I'll change it to `form`, and I'm not sure that a MessageBox counts as a form.

Comment: @tijizor definitely true. `Enter` or `Space` clicks the active, focused button. You can move that focus the the D-pad or by clicking on another button but releasing the click off the button.