# Close MUI Snackbar notification and perform action on keypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

We have created a notification system that uses the material ui Snackbar with an action button and close button. I'm trying to add a listener event for `enter` so that specific notification's action will fire and close the Snackbar. I attempted to do this when the component is mounted, but the components mount when the application loads they are just not shown until their state is set to `open`. This resulted in all the actions attached to the Snackbars firing at once. I then attempted to use a ref but had no success. Below I will show the code for the button that calls the notifications and the notification component itself. I'm looking for suggestions on how to close the active Snackbar and fire off its action with `enter` without activating the other mounted notifications.

UPDATE: I changed the key from `enter` to `spacebar` and it works as desired. It seems the issue lies with the `enter` key itself.

https://material-ui.com/api/root-ref/#__next

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import { NotifierConfirm, enqueueInfo } from '@paragon/notification-tools';
import { deleteDocument } from '../../actions/documents';
import { getSelectedDocument } from '../../selectors/documents';
import { jobIsLocked } from '../../modules/jobLocking'; // eslint-disable-line

const styles = ({
  border: {
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
});

class DeleteDocument extends React.Component {
  state = {
    deleteDocumentOpen: false,
  }

  onDeleteFile = () => {
    if (jobIsLocked()) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({ deleteDocumentOpen: true });
  }

  closeDeleteDocument = () => {
    this.setState({ deleteDocumentOpen: false });
  };

  onConfirmDelete = () => {
    this.props.onDeleteFile(this.props.selectedDocument.id);
    this.setState({ deleteDocumentOpen: false });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Tooltip disableFocusListener id="delete-tooltip" title="Delete Document">
          <div>
            <IconButton
              className={`${classes.border} deleteDocumentButton`}
              disabled={(this.props.selectedDocument == null)}
              onClick={this.onDeleteFile}
            >
              <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Tooltip>
        <NotifierConfirm
          open={this.state.deleteDocumentOpen}
          onClose={this.closeDeleteDocument}
          onClick={this.onConfirmDelete}
          message="Are you sure you want to DELETE this document?"
          buttonText="Delete"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const selectedDocument = getSelectedDocument(state);

  return {
    selectedDocument,
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onDeleteFile: (documentId) => {
      dispatch(deleteDocument(documentId));
    },
    enqueueInfo,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(DeleteDocument));
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles, WithStyles, StyleRulesCallback } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import RootRef from '@material-ui/core/RootRef';

interface NotifierConfirmProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: any;
  onClick: () => void;
  message: string;
  messageSecondary?: any;
  buttonText: string;
}

type OwnProps = NotifierConfirmProps & WithStyles<typeof styles>;

const styles: StyleRulesCallback = () => ({
  snackbar: {
    marginTop: 85,
    zIndex: 10000000,
    '& div:first-child': {
      '& div:first-child': {
        width: '100%',
      },
    },
  },
  close: {
    padding: 8,
    marginLeft: 8,
  },
  buttonColor: {
    backgroundColor: '#F3D06E',
  },
  messageDiv: {
    width: '100%',
  }
});

class NotifierConfirmComponent extends React.Component<OwnProps> {
  notifierRef: React.RefObject<{}>;
  constructor(props: OwnProps) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.notifierRef = React.createRef();
    this.focusNotifier = this.focusNotifier.bind(this);
  }
  keyPressHandler = (event: any) => {
    if (!this.props.open) return;
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      this.props.onClose();
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      this.props.onClick();
    }
  }

  focusNotifier() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    // this.notifierRef.current.focus();  this will not work
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyPressHandler, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyPressHandler, false);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <RootRef rootRef={this.notifierRef}>
          <Snackbar
            className={classes.snackbar}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: 'top',
              horizontal: 'center',
            }}
            open={this.props.open}
            onClose={this.props.onClose}
            ContentProps={{
              'aria-describedby': 'message-id',
            }}
            message={
              <div className={classes.messageDiv} id="message-id">
                {this.props.message}<br />
                {this.props.messageSecondary}
              </div>}
            action={[
              <Button
                className={`${classes.buttonColor} confirmActionButton`}
                variant="contained"
                key={this.props.buttonText}
                size="small"
                onClick={this.props.onClick}
              >
                {this.props.buttonText}
              </Button>,
              <IconButton
                key="close"
                aria-label="Close"
                color="inherit"
                className={classes.close}
                onClick={this.props.onClose}
              >
                <CloseIcon />
              </IconButton>,
            ]}
          />
        </RootRef>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export const NotifierConfirm = withStyles(styles)(NotifierConfirmComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this was changing the event listener to `keyup` instead of 
 `keydown`. Deduced this from this post. [Why do Enter and Space keys behave differently for buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090578/why-do-enter-and-space-keys-behave-differently-for-buttons)